# How to continue a Transaction on multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have 3 HTML Forms on 3 different PHP Pages which are used to insert data in 3 different tables.

Current Process is as follows:

- User Fills First Form & click on "Next" (data is inserted in 1st table in database)
- User Fills Second Form & click "Next" (data is stored in 2nd table in database)
- User Fills Third Form & click "Finish" (data is stored in 3rd table in database)

I want:

commit must be issued only in case when user fills all 3 Forms & click Finish. If user quits/exits on any stage before filling all three forms, all data stored in tables should be roll-backed.

Can I use Laravel `DB::Transaction` or I have any other option? Please give any suggestion.

Actually in each steps user can add multiple records in one table. For example on 3rd step user can add as many records in `subjects` table as he wants. I use following code to save these multiple records in table `subjects`:

```
for($i=1; $i<=Input::get('total_subjects'); $i++){
    if(Input::get('sub_'.$i) != null){
    $sd = new Subject;
    $sd->class_detail_id = Input::get('class_detail_id');
    $sd->subject_id = Input::get('sub_'.$i);
    $sd->status = 'ACTIVE';
    $sd->save();
}
```

**Now problem is:** 
How is it Possible to store *References* to all Models of `Subject` ?
The only solution that comes to my mind is to make a transaction and `COMMIT` only after 3rd step otherwise transaction will be Roll-backed.

Comment: I am assigned the same task and I went for Justinas solution below. Although it is technically possible to keep a PHP process active during several HTTP requests, it is not clever and practical to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not put form data to temp session variable and only after completing step 3 insert all data from session to database?

*Why to use this method instead?*

1) There is no trash in database.
2) Session auto-cleans itself after user leaves your webpage (willingly or by accident).
3) You can move freely between steps and all info will be auto-filled or return.
4) Only one connection to database - faster website.
5) Enables you to use transactions.

Comment: It would be a good answer if you elaborate the pro's and con's for several solutions. Until then this is not more than a comment.